# Automatically update 1 webform based on values of other webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am using a webform to gather candidate application details for employment.

I have attachment fields where candidate can upload their  files ex: Marksheet, Experience letter,etc.

Each Form has attachment field relevant to the form. Ex Personal Info form  has Photo, Education details has Marksheets as attachment field.

I have 1 last form as All Attachments where there is a list of all files(i.e file names of attachments from all webforms ).

Can anyone please tell me, is it possible that when a candidate fills out 1 form with attachment, that same attachmnet name gets automatically check marked on last form.
I am beginner and new to drupal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely can be done - as most things in Drupal / PHP. Will require a bit of coding though as I don't know any modules that do this out of the box.

Basically all you'd have to do is alter the webform so that the webform would be pre-filled with that value if there's a submission of the other form by that user.

To achieve this, the best way is to probably use a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter the form and then use `webform_get_submissions()` to load the submissions of the other webforms, check if there's a submission by this user already and update the current webform accordingly.